# Laravel5 How to Update latest data and get true accumulative sum to database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

Good day to you, I want ask something that I can't solve this from 2 days ago, I have problem when I imported data to the database

example:

I have entry like this in my csv file that I will import

```
||=============================================||
|| wholesaler || product || week_01 || week_02 ||
||=============================================||
|| Michael    || Tomato  || 90.000  || 60.000  ||
|| Michael    || Apple   || 50.000  || 50.000  ||
|| Santi      || Mango   || 23.000  || 32.000  ||
||=============================================||
```

When I import that file, everything is ok, I check in database it will look like this

```
||==================================================================================||
|| wholesaler || target  || period  || total_transaction || rebate || total_voucher ||
||==================================================================================||
|| Michael    || 100.000 || 01.2017 ||      140.000      ||   2%   ||      2800     ||
|| Michael    || 100.000 || 02.2017 ||      250.000      ||   2%   ||      2200     ||
|| Santi      || 100.000 || 01.2017 ||      23.000       ||   2%   ||        0      ||
|| Santi      || 100.000 || 02.2017 ||      55.000       ||   2%   ||        0      ||
||==================================================================================||
```

But when I add new entry to my file like this

```
||=============================================||
|| wholesaler || product || week_01 || week_02 ||
||=============================================||
||  Michael   || Tomato ||  90.000  || 60.000  ||
||  Michael   || Apple  ||  50.000  || 50.000  ||
||  Santi     || Mango  ||  23.000  || 32.000  ||
||  Santi     || Apple  ||  11.000  || 33.000  ||---->  NEW ENTRY
||=============================================||
```

And I import the file, then something wrong is appear in database

```
||=====================================================================================||
||  wholesaler ||   target  ||  period || total_transaction || rebate || total_voucher ||
||=====================================================================================||
||  Michael    ||  100.000  || 01.2017 ||       140.000     ||   2%   ||     2800      ||
||  Michael    ||  100.000  || 02.2017 ||       250.000     ||   2%   ||     2200      ||
||   Santi     ||  100.000  || 01.2017 ||       23.000      ||   2%   ||       0       ||
||   Santi     ||  100.000  || 02.2017 ||       55.000      ||   2%   ||       0       ||
||   Santi     ||  100.000  || 01.2017 ||       34.000      ||   2%   ||       0       ||-->  this total_transaction is correct, base on sum 23.000 + 11.000
||   Santi     ||  100.000  || 02.2017 ||       78.000      ||   2%   ||       0       ||-->  but this is not correct
||=====================================================================================||
```

It must be like this:

```
||=====================================================================================||
|| wholesaler ||  target ||  period || total_transaction || rebate || total_voucher    ||
||=====================================================================================||
||  Michael   || 100.000 || 01.2017 ||       140.000     ||   2%   ||     2800         ||
||  Michael   || 100.000 || 02.2017 ||       250.000     ||   2%   ||     2200         ||
||  Santi     || 100.000 || 01.2017 ||        34.000     ||   2%   ||      0           ||-->  sum week_01 
||  Santi     || 100.000 || 02.2017 ||        99.000     ||   2%   ||      0           ||-->  sum week_01+sum week_02 
||=====================================================================================||
```

This is the code in Controller:

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('leveredge');
$now = $request->input('week');
for($x = 13; $x <= $now + 12; $x++)
{
    $total_transaction = Leveredge::groupBy('distributor', 'outlet')->selectRaw('distributor, outlet, sum(week_'. str_pad($x-12, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) .') AS sum')->get();
    $y = 0;

    foreach($total_transaction as $row)
    {
        $wholesaler_id = $row->outlet;

        $wholesaler = Wholesaler::find($wholesaler_id);


        $target = '';

        if( $wholesaler && ($wholesaler->total_target != -1 && $wholesaler->q1 != -1 && $wholesaler->q2 != -1 && $wholesaler->q3 != -1 && $wholesaler->q4 != -1) )
        {
            $wholesaler_type = WholesalerType::find($wholesaler->wholesaler_type_id);
            $week = substr($columns[$x], -2);
            if($week <= 13){
                $target = is_null($wholesaler->q1)? 0 : $wholesaler->q1;
            }else if($week <= 26 && $week >= 14){
                $target = is_null($wholesaler->q2)? 0 : $wholesaler->q2;
            }else if($week <= 39 && $week >= 27){
                $target = is_null($wholesaler->q3)? 0 : $wholesaler->q3;
            }else if($week >= 28){
                $target = is_null($wholesaler->q4)? 0 : $wholesaler->q4;
            }else{
                $target = 0;
            }

            $match = ['wholesaler_id' => $wholesaler_id, 'week' => str_pad($week-1, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '.' . date("Y")];
            $last_transaction = Voucher::where($match)->first();

            $curr_sum = $row->sum;
            $sum = $row->sum;

            $total_voucher = 0;
            if(!in_array($week, [1, 14, 27, 52])){
                $sum += $last_transaction->total_transaction;
                if($sum >= $target){
                    if($last_transaction->total_transaction == $sum){
                        $total_voucher = 0;
                    }else if($last_transaction->total_voucher == 0){
                        $total_voucher = ($wholesaler_type->rebate_percentage/100 * $sum);
                    }else{
                        $total_voucher = ($wholesaler_type->rebate_percentage/100 * $curr_sum);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if($sum >= $target){
                    $total_voucher = ($wholesaler_type->rebate_percentage/100 * $curr_sum);
                }else{
                    $total_voucher = 0;
                }
            }


           $voucher = Voucher::firstOrCreate(array(
                'wholesaler_id' => $wholesaler_id,
                'target' => $target,
                'week' => $week . '.' . date("Y"),
                'total_transaction' => $sum,
                'rebate' => $wholesaler_type->rebate_percentage,
                'total_voucher' => $total_voucher
            ));

            $leveredgenotification = LeveredgeNotification::firstOrCreate(array(
                'wholesaler_id'    => $voucher->wholesaler_id,
                'value'            => $voucher->total_voucher,
                'target'           => '0',
                'type'             => 'cashback_voucher',
                'status'           => 99,
            ));
        }
        $y++;
    }
}
```

I hope you can help to solve this problem,
Thank you so much.
Have a nice day.

Comment: you may want to distinct the `wholesaler` and `period` to remove duplicate records

Comment: i want the total_transaction collumn is accumulative sum correctly and updating the database, not create :)

Comment: `to not get duplicated data`

Comment: umm sorry maybe i must change the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finnaly it solved: 
i modify the firstorCreate to like this:

```
$voucher = Voucher::firstOrNew(array(
                            'wholesaler_id' => $wholesaler_id,
                            'target' => $target,
                            'week' => $week . '.' . date("Y")
                        ));
                       $voucher->wholesaler_id = $wholesaler_id;
                       $voucher->target = $target;
                       $voucher->week = $week . '.' . date("Y");
                       $voucher->total_transaction = $sum;
                       $voucher->rebate = $wholesaler_type->rebate_percentage;
                       $voucher->total_voucher = $total_voucher;
                       $voucher->save();
```

thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Use `->groupBy('wholesaler')` on your query.

## Example:

```
Wholesaler::find($wholesaler_id)->groupBy('wholesaler');
```

Comment: when i import, it will appear error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$total_target

Comment: @FaisalHilmi can you show us the line where the error occurred?

Comment: @RahmaniSaif there is no error but the problem is it create new entry in database, i want update :)